# Change java binary used by android sdk

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-doctor

How do I change the Java Binary used by the android SDK. I installed a different JDK and would like to use that. I have tried changing the JDK path in android Studio but that doesn't change it.

```
    • Flutter version 2.4.0-1.0.pre.45 at /Users/nonybrighto/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository unknown
    • Framework revision 52e2ca38fc (4 weeks ago), 2021-07-01 15:06:05 -0700
    • Engine revision e499100bb2
    • Dart version 2.14.0 (build 2.14.0-263.0.dev)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/nonybrighto/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.5.1, Build version 12E507
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
```

It currently uses the JDK that comes with Android Studio
`Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java`

Comment: Probably from right click on the project then module settings.